# Fillbetween not displaying when compiled

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

Below is a minimal example of a script which reads in data from a file and then fills in the region defined by the plot below the x axis and the x axis itself. The input file can be found here:

http://expirebox.com/download/0055b781a018392f326c55e6946707ca.html

The issue is that it does not display the shading when compiled, and it does not give back any errors to suggest there is an issue. I use LuaLaTex, but have tried XeLaTex and PDFLaTex and all do not show the shading. Is there an issue with the way I have defined the paths or an issue with the data itself?

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis} [name=mainplot,clip mode=individual,
        %width=\textwidth,
        axis y line=left,
        y axis line style=<->,
        x axis line style=->,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        xtick align=inside,
        ytick align=inside,
        axis x line=middle,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=8,
        ymax=0.7,
        ytick={-0.1,0,...,0.8},
        ymin=-0.1,
        minor y tick num =3,
        minor x tick num =1,
        restrict x to domain=/pgfplots/xmin:/pgfplots/xmax,
        ]
        \addplot[name path=A,blue,thick] table[x=x,y=w] {input_file.txt};
        \path[name path=B](\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0)--(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

        \addplot fill between[of=A and B,
                            split,
                            every segment no 1/.style=
                            {pattern=north east lines},
                            every segment no 2/.style=
                            {fill=none},
                            ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is shown below; the goal is to shade the region beneath the x-axis and bounded by the plot (i.e. 0 -> ~3).

Many thanks in advance

Yeti

[image: fillbetween from data file]

Comment: I replaced your input (which is a dead link) by some dummy function between y=-0.1 and y=0.7 and it works fine -- after adding `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`. You will either need to readd the data file or provide more information such that we can reproduce the issue